# VBA / Selenium – Set string values to run a script

Tags: excel, vba, string, selenium-webdriver, set

In order to run the script shown here, this line works fine:

```
ChromoLink.ExecuteScript ("document.getElementById('entity.cdCredor').value = '28260'")
```

But, when I set values to run the script as string, it’s not working:

```
Dim Customer As String
Customer = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -10).Value
```

'Attempt 1:

```
ChromoLink.ExecuteScript ("document.getElementById('entity.cdCredor').value = Customer")
```

'Attempt 2:

```
ChromoLink.ExecuteScript ("document.getElementById('entity.cdCredor').value = (Customer)")
```

'Attempt 3:

```
ChromoLink.ExecuteScript ("document.getElementById('entity.cdCredor').value = 'Customer'")
```

'Attempt 4:

```
ChromoLink.ExecuteScript ("document.getElementById('entity.cdCredor').value = ('Customer')")
```

What can I do to get it working?

Comment: `ChromoLink.ExecuteScript ("document.getElementById('entity.cdCredor').value = '" & Costumer & "'")`

Comment: That was absolutely perferct...Cheers